# Upload react basic application to server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serverside-javascript

I am trying to upload the following to my personal server to see how it works:

https://github.com/remarkablemark/universal-react-tutorial

I have tried to change the port here: (server.js)

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['react']
});

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(require('./routes/index.jsx'));

var PORT = 80;
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('http://localhost:' + PORT);
});
```

but when I type the corresponding url I get this:

**

```
Index of /ReactServer
Parent Directory
Component.jsx
client.js
public/
routes/
server.js
webpack.config.js
Apache Server at www.alessandrosantese.com Port 80
```

**

I can see the app working fine at http://localhost:3000/ but I would like to test it on the server (I have never deployed a react application on a live server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of deploying `node.js` to remote server.

I would recommend you to use **heroku**
Follow [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) steps to deploy your app easily to their servers.